# I am trying to pull data from devOps using an API but am receiving a 401 unauthorized error

Tags: python, flask, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/odata", methods=["GET"])

def main():
    token = 'my-token-is-here'
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f"Bearer {token}",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    url="https://analytics.dev.azure.com/krisn916/newProject/_odata/v4.0-preview/WorkItems?    $top=10"
    response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)


    if response.status_code == 200:
        userData = response.json()
        return jsonify(userData), 200

    return jsonify({"error": "Failed to fetch user data"}), response.status_code


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My token is correct and pulled directly from devOps. I also have full access with my token. What are possible reasons I could be getting a 401 unauthorized?

I tried to pull my data from devOps using an API. I expected to pull my data with a 200 status code. What actually happened was I received a 401 status.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for how to authenticate with a PAT? It should be `Basic`, not `Bearer`.

Comment: @DanielMann i still get this: 
`{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF400813: The user 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' is not authorized to access this resource.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.UnauthorizedRequestException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server","typeKey":"UnauthorizedRequestException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}`

Answer (score 0):

***I made some changes with your code and got my 10 work items details from Azure Devops.***

These are the work items I have created in my Azure Devops as below,

[image]

**Code:**

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/odata', methods=['GET'])
def get_work_items():
    PAT = "<personal-access-token>"
    base_url = "https://dev.azure.com/<organization-name>/<project-name>/_apis/wit/"
    work_item_ids = [<10-work-item-ID'S>] 

    work_items = []
    try:
        for work_item_id in work_item_ids:

            response = requests.get(base_url + f"workitems/{work_item_id}?api-version=6.0", headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + PAT})
            response.raise_for_status()

            data = response.json()
            title = data["fields"]["System.Title"]
            state = data["fields"]["System.State"]
            assigned_to = data["fields"].get("System.AssignedTo", {}).get("displayName", "N/A")
            description = data["fields"].get("System.Description", "N/A")

            work_item = {
                "Work Item ID": work_item_id,
                "Title": title,
                "State": state,
                "Assigned To": assigned_to,
                "Description": description
            }
            work_items.append(work_item)

        return jsonify(work_items)

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as ex:
        return f"Error: {str(ex)}", 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**Output:**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

With the above URL, I got my 10 work item details from Azure Devops as below,

[image]
[image]